# How do I move a form's onPaint event to a custom class?

Tags: c#, themes, custom-controls

I have an application where I'm styling some forms by using my own "ThemeManager" class. Fairly basic stuff - I'm used to working with CSS for web apps, and am writing this as a forms app (can't be WPF for various reasons).

As such, I'm styling the forms using a ThemeManager class, where I can pass the forms to be styled:

Example from the Theme Manager:

> public void setTheme(Form sender)
>           {
>               // Set background and foreground colors
>               sender.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#222222");
>               sender.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A6CE39");

```
        // Loop through controls on form
        foreach (Control c in sender.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Button) // Set the button style
            {
                Button btn = c as Button;
                btn.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#222222");
                btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                btn.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            }

            if ((c is ComboBox) || (c is TextBox)) // Set dropdown and textbox style
            { 
                c.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A6CE39");
                c.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2e2e2e");
            }
        }

    }
```

The forms have no title bar and border, but I want to set a very simple border on them. At the moment I do this by setting an onPaint event on each form:

```
        public void RemoteControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A6CE39"), 3),
                       this.DisplayRectangle); 
    }
```

With this in the designer:

```
            this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.RemoteControl_Paint);
```

However, I have to do this on each form, whereas I'd rather do it via the Theme Manager.

I've tried adding this to the SetTheme method:

```
 sender.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(MyForm_Paint);
```

And adding this method to the ThemeManager.cs class:

```
 private void MyForm_Paint(Form sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A6CE39"), 3),
                       sender.DisplayRectangle);
    }
```

This doesn't work - I get an overload error:

```
No overload for 'MyForm_Paint' matches delegate 'System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler'
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PaintEventHandler` delegate (which is the type behind the `Paint` event) takes a `sender` parameter of type `Object`, not `Form`.  (like all other standard event delegates)

If you change your handler method to take `object sender` (then cast it back to `Form`), it will work fine.